# How to restart slide numbering from 1 in new section in MS PowerPoint 2013?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I am using two sections in my presentation and I want slide numbering to restart after the end of 1st section and at the start of next section.

Answer (score 1):

PowerPoint has no method for doing this.

Something similar could be accomplished using a bit of VBA (ie, a macro), but it wouldn't be a beginner project to write such a thing.  If you'd like to have a go at it, I can outline how you might go about getting started.  Then if you run into difficulties, pop back into StackOverflow.com with your code, a detailed description of the problem and someone should be able to help you.